# Equivalent of Ruby's Array.pack in Elixir

Tags: elixir

There is an application on ruby that works with packed arrays:

```
2.3.1 :001 > [3340546, 3340547].pack("L*")
 => "\x02\xF92\x00\x03\xF92\x00" 
2.3.1 :002 > "\x02\xF92\x00\x03\xF92\x00".unpack("L*")
 => [3340546, 3340547]
```

is there an option to make a pack for an array on Elixir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! In Elixir we use binary pattern matching to achieve this. `L` in Ruby's pack/unpack is for a 32 bit unsigned little endian integer. Here's how you'd do those two operations in Elixir:

Pack:

```
iex(1)> <<3340546::32-little, 3340547::32-little>>
<<2, 249, 50, 0, 3, 249, 50, 0>>
```

Unpack:

```
iex(2)> <<a::32-little, b::32-little>> = "\x02\xF92\x00\x03\xF92\x00"
<<2, 249, 50, 0, 3, 249, 50, 0>>
iex(3)> a
3340546
iex(4)> b
3340547
```

You can also pack/unpack a list of arbitrary number of values like this:

```
iex(5)> Enum.map_join([3340546, 3340547], fn x -> <<x::32-little>> end)
<<2, 249, 50, 0, 3, 249, 50, 0>>
iex(6)> for <<x::32-little <- "\x02\xF92\x00\x03\xF92\x00">>, do: x
[3340546, 3340547]
```